# Distance between coordinates in Big-oh of M time

Tags: algorithm, grid-layout

I have an array of coordinates, i.e each index contains (x,y) coordinates. I want to figure out that if any of the coordinates are in single row or column. The challenge is to do in a single loop where M is the length of the array. I have been trying hard but cant seem to do it without using two loops. Just need help with the algorithm.

Edit: Basically the problem is that I have M pieces on an N by N board. Each piece can move any vertically and horizontally by any number. Just want to figure out that if any piece can attack any other piece.

Comment: Is this a generalization of the 8 queens problem? Your array contains only the coordinates on the board of the queens and you want to tell in a single pass through that array if any queen is attacking any other queen?

Comment: Its actually a easier version

Comment: So a generalization of 8 rooks? If there's more than 1 on any row or any column, then at least two pieces are attacking each other?

Comment: exactly, the only dumb solution I have in my mind is to apply count sort on both rows and columns, get two different frequency arrays and then loop over them. it is still a Big-oh M solution. But not happy with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [element distinctness/uniqueness problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem) that has complexity O(MLogm) in common case (i.e. sorting).

If there are no memory limitations, you can use hash tables for Y and X coordinates, in this case single run through array solves the problem

**Edit:** For limited board it is simpler to use boolean array length N for horizontals and verticals. Time complexity O(M), memory consumption O(N)

```
for every rook:
    if Horiz[rook.Y] then
        two rooks share horizontal
    if Vert[rook.X] then
        two rooks share the same vertical
    Horiz[rook.Y] = True
    Vert[rook.X] = True
```

Comment: Basically the problem is that I have M pieces on an N by N board. Each piece can move any vertically and horizontally by any number. Just want to figure out that if any piece can attack any other piece.

Comment: All remains right. Time O(M) for this definition. For limited board it is simpler to use arrays instead of hash table. Arrays with length N for vertical and horizontals - memory consumption O(N)

Comment: Can you please elaborate more?