# Interview prep: K Queen attack

Tags: algorithm, grid-layout

I have an N by N grid and K queens in it. 
The queen can move vertically, horizontally or diagonally. I want to figure out if any queen can attack any other queen in O(N) time.

Comment: Hi @hassam-ullah-sheikh, welcome to SO or sort of ... SO is not an code/algorithm outsourcing facility. You need to show your due diligence before asking for help. Where is your [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about programming as defined by the help center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same technique as in [the last answer for rook problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41994479/844416), just add arrays for diagonals.  `DiagUpRight[2*N-1]` and `DiagUpLeft[2*N-1]`.

Q(x,y) marks diagonals `DiagUpLeft[x + y]` and `DiagUpRight[N-1 - y + x]`

Answer (score 0):

Let `q_row` and `q_col` denote the row and the column of queen q. Then you can solve your problem with this pseudo code:

```
for each q in Queens do
    if row[q_row] or column[q_col] or 
       diag1[N + q_row - q_col] or diag2[q_row + q_col] then
        output 'Attacking queen found.'
        break
    else
        row[q_row] = true
        column[q_col] = true
        diag1[N + q_row - q_col] = true
        diag2[q_row + q_col] = true
```

Comment: Thanks. Dont understand why cant i think if these easy steps. Probably sleep deprivation

Comment: or maybe you were waiting for someone to do the work for you ...

Comment: Feel free to think whatever you like.